# EJB 2.0 myql connector jar is not bundled in the final jar

Tags: java, mysql, ejb

In my EJB 2.0 project, when I try to invoke a method(with code to make jdbc connection) from client, the ClassNotFoundException is encountered for mysql driver even I have added mysqlconnector jar.

Comment: EJB is a complex topic; and without further details such questions are impossible to answer (what container? where did you deploy mysql connector? where do get an exception? code example? why on earth ejb 2.0?)

Comment: I am thankful to you for helping me. I just created a simple project with a session bean implementing the method and that particular method is called using a main method on client. If I simply print something in a particular method, the it is working fine. But I write code to get connection with db, It gives ClassNotFoundException for mysql.Driver, hence seems some jar not loading issue to me. I have added the mysqlconnector jar in ejmodule by clicking on configure build path in eclipse